# Gulp - list all files as a separated tasks

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer, gulp-plugin

I want to list all the .ts files from a partucar folder, and present them as an individual tasks using gulp.

So, i have a folder which have those files:

```
/src
 - app.ts
 - items.ts
```

Right now I'm using this command to build all those files and send them to a specific destination:

```
 var gulp = reguire('gulp');
 var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
 var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

 gulp.task('build:ts', () => {
   return tsProject.src().pipe(tsProject())
     .js.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
 });
```

So this gets all the `.ts` files from `./src` and add them into the `./dist` folder as compiled `.js files`

What i want to do is:

- list all the .ts files in my task runner
- right click on a particular task(file)
- run build:ts just for that particular ts file
- compile and add that particular file into ./dist